# Tangent grooming with geometry nodes

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to make hair particles follow the uv tangent of a mesh, in the old hair particles it was easy, but there is no UVtangent node in geometry nodes yet, so how to achieve it? I tried baking the uvtangent, but I don't know how to use it to achieve the same effect.

Example of what I want:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after lots of tinkering I found a solution. First you need to make sure to bake to a 32-bit Float OpenEXR texture set to Non-Color. That way you do not get any compresion artefacts.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I work in aces so I set it to Utility-Raw, do this bevor saving.

Then I distributed some points on the faces and instanced short curves on them. Thiere end points I then moved based on the tangent map. First I scaled all the legnths to -1 to 1 and then set X of the mapto Y and Z to X.
Throw that to a scale and set it as the offset of a Set Position node with Selection on the end points.
Then I did a Interpolate hair curves with the starting curves as guides, make sure to set amount of guides to something higher.

Here is a blend file:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: That work perfectly, thank you!
Can't wait to have this built-in geometry nodes.